# Как написать пять нулей?

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая заполняет число 0. Один байт состоит из 8 бит. пример 101 = 00000101. Я хотел написать программу, но не понял как написать пять нолей перед 101.

```
a = input()
b = 8 - len(a)
print(b)
```

А потом, как сделать что бы пять нолей с начала, я не знаю.

Comment: так `print("0"*b)`

Comment: капец я умственно отсталый, спасибо

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Используйте метод строки `zfill`:

```
print('101'.zfill(8))
# 00000101
```

Пример:

```
a = input()
b = a.zfill(8)
print(b)
```

**S.zfill**(width), где **S** - строка, делает длину строки не меньшей width, по необходимости заполняя первые символы нулями.
[Справка.](https://docs.python.org/release/3.6.15/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=zfill#str.zfill)

Answer (score 5):

**вариант 1:**

```
a = input()
b = 8 - len(a)
print(f'{"0" * b}{a}')
```

**вариант 2:**

```
a = input()
print(('0' * 8 + a)[-8:])
```

Comment: С использованием f-строк вообще какой-то ядрёный смайлик получился - `f"{a:0>8}"`. :)

Answer (score 5):

Если через f-строки, то даже длину считать не надо.

```
b = f"{a:0>8}"
```

Comment: я вот не нашел как через f-строку такой формат задать :(

Comment: @Zhihar, `b = "{:0>8}".format(a)` :)

Comment: А вот это уже для начинающих просто "отвал башки"! Начинающие, не переживайте! Эти дяди, которые с "большими очками рейтинга", то же когда-то были начинающими... так что - "Только вперед!"

Answer (score 1):

Для коллекции добавляю ещё одно экзотическое решение, без строковых операций, только использующее конвертацию между системами счисления (двоичной и десятичной) (конечно, на заднем плане в неявном виде там работа со строками всё таки идёт).

Заодно, моя микро-программа проверяет корректность введённых данных, что введено именно целое число только из `0` и `1` цифр и ничего кроме, если введено что то другое - будет исключение.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIykzT8PI1ExBWwHEy8wrKC3R0NRRMNLUjDa2itX8/9/QwBAA)

```py
print(bin(256 + int(input(), 2))[3:])
```

Ввод:

```
101
```

Вывод:

```
00000101
```